# Manipulate string in column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
a = data.frame("a" = c("aaa|abbb", "bbb|aaa", "bbb|aaa|ccc"), "b" = c(1,2,3))

     a       b
 aaa|abbb    1
 bbb|aaa     2
 bbb|aaa|ccc 3
```

I want to split the colum value by "|" and sort the output and merge them together to look like this

```
     a       b
 aaa|abbb    1
 aaa|bbb     2
|aaa|bbb|ccc 3
```

I tried to use following

```
paste(sort(ignore.case(unlist(strsplit(as.character(a$a), "\\|")))),collapse = ", ")
```

but that just combine everything together. How can I implement it on each value of column A and get the result as dataframe. I tried to use lapply but still got the same result, one combined list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(a$a), '|', fixed = TRUE), function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = '|'))
#[1] "aaa|abbb"    "aaa|bbb"     "aaa|bbb|ccc"
```

So to update your column a, just assign it back to it, i.e.

```
a$a <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(a$a), '|', fixed = TRUE), function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = '|'))
```

Comment: How would i convert it back to column and put it back in the original data frame. I guess i would have to replace column "a" value with these and keep the other column "b" intact.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know If you have any more questions

Answer (score 4):

We could use `separate_rows` to split the values in 'a', then grouped by 'b', `sort` 'a' and `paste` the elements together

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% 
 separate_rows(a) %>% 
 group_by(b) %>% 
 summarise(a = paste(sort(a), collapse="|")) %>%
 select(names(a))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a               b
#  <chr>       <dbl>
#1 aaa|abbb        1
#2 aaa|bbb         2
#3 aaa|bbb|ccc     3
```

Comment: Thats thorws me error and I have so many tidyverse_conflicts().

Comment: @user1631306  Can you just load `library(dplyr);library(tidyr)`

Comment: I have to use so many other libraries for other purpose in my code. But that seems to be a nice solution. thanks for helping me out. The other answer worked great for me.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Sotos's answer:

```
a$clean <- sapply(as.character(a$a), function(i) paste(sort(tolower(unlist(strsplit(i, split = "|", fixed = TRUE)))), collapse = "|"))

#             a b       clean
# 1    aaa|abbb 1    aaa|abbb
# 2     bbb|aaa 2     aaa|bbb
# 3 bbb|aaa|ccc 3 aaa|bbb|ccc
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("a b
aaa|abbb 1
bbb|aaa 2
bbb|aaa|ccc 3")
dat[,a_sorted :=sapply(lapply(strsplit(a, "\\|"), sort),paste,collapse="|") ]
```